# django urls and generic view

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

i want to set up a generic view that will do some things and then will call an specific view
example:

main project urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^(?P<application>\w+)/', 'tool.start.start'),
```

myapp urls:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.view',
    (r'^$', 'dashboard'),
```

this will execute my view "start" and will passing it "application" parameter
in view "start" i wanna check and set up some vars then i wanna execute specific view  as described in application.urls

so if i call "localhost:8080/myapp" first execute tool.start.start then myapp.view.dashboard

i've tryed to include application.urls and resolve it but nothing ...

any idea?

Comment: I'm wondering why you would want to call two views in a row. If there is code that you need to run at the start of each request you should probably be using a [middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/?from=olddocs).

Answer (score 0):

Any functionality that needs to be executed before or after a view should be placed in a [Middleware](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/). In example:

```
class CustomMiddleware(object):

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs): 

        if view_func == dashboard:
            tool.start.start(request)
```